# Bigquery standard sql function for DATE_FORMAT(CONVERT_TZ(NOW(),'+00:00','-07:00'),'%Y-%m-%d %r')

Tags: google-bigquery

Could you please help me in getting the standard sql function equivalent to legacy sql function DATE_FORMAT(CONVERT_TZ(NOW(),'+00:00','-07:00'),'%Y-%m-%d %r')

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standrad SQL

```
CURRENT_DATE('-07:00')
```

or you might want below

```
FORMAT_DATETIME('%Y-%m-%d %r',DATETIME(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), '-07:00'))
```

Comment: sure. consider also voting up the answer if it helped